# Rewrite rule for 403

Tags: htaccess, 403-forbidden

I have an *.htaccess* file:

In this file it redirects to `index.php` in case a file or directory is not found.

My code is as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working fine with this code. Now when I get Forbidden error(403), I would like it to be redirect to `index.php`.

Do you have an idea how to write an *.htaccess* file for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `ErrorDocument` rule. Using your example, it might look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>    
ErrorDocument 403 index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer you great bro... your answer was not exact but found the way...thanks again